# Criando Event no MYSQL para excluir registros por dia

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando criar um evento automático no MySQL para que a cada 24 horas ele execute o seguinte comando para excluir promoções sem a interação do administrador, onde se a data de término for menor que a data atual irá excluir, não tenho certeza se funciona.

```
CREATE EVENT excluirPromocao
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO 
DELETE FROM promocao where data_termino < NOW();
```

//Novo evento

```
CREATE EVENT 
    EXCLUIR_PROMOCAO
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 
    24 HOUR
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO 
DELETE FROM 
    promocao 
WHERE 
    data_termino < CURDATE();
```

Comment: é no formato date

Comment: Opa, desculpa é a data de termino menor que a data atual

Comment: Duas observações, verifique no seu my.ini a variável event_scheduler, ela tem que estar com valor 1 para funcionar, após alterar caso necessite reinicie o serviço do MySQL, segundo ponto é o tipo de dado que está no seu campo data_termino, se for um datetime está ok, mas se for apenas um date altere a clausula where para: where data_termino < DATE(NOW());